# Forensic wipe a file from hard disk in C

Tags: c, winapi

I know how to go about forensic wiping a complete disk for example. I could just use createfile and then writefile to write the entire disk. For example D:\ with random garbage bits of data so that when I fire up a utility like easus recovery manager, I won't be able to find any trace of any file or recover them. Now I'm trying to accomplish the same with a particular file or directory in a disk. Suppose there is a file called Test.txt and I want to delete it and also fill the space occupied by it with garbage values so the space is not left out to be overwritten as windows usually works. Is it possible to do it in C? If so, how do I go about it? A code snippet would be extremely helpful!

Comment: Um, the exact same way you do with a full disk.  Simply `CreateFile()` to open the file, then `WriteFile()` to write garbage to the file, then `CloseHandle()` to close the file, and `DeleteFile()` to delete the file.  Alternatively, you can use `CreateFile()`+`CreateFileMapping()`+`MapViewOfFile()` to map the file into memory, and then you can write garbage into the memory, which will write it directly to the file.

Comment: Not so easy on an SSD though.

Comment: Just trying to write over the existing file might not clear the contents of the old file from the disk, especially if the original file is not stored contiguously.

Comment: Now, theres where the problem starts. Will the writefile value be written at Test.txt+1 location or at Test.txt location. Because it would be pointless to writefile at Test.txt+1 as that would overwrite some other data possibly and also not delete the Test.txt or fill it up with garbage values.

Comment: When you open a file, its current position starts at 0, so writing new data to the file will overwrite existing data in the file. To overwrite the whole file, simply retrieve the file's current size, and then write that many new bytes to the file.

Comment: @FredK Exactly! How do I go about doing it to individual files?

Comment: Remy, if you suggest a way to do it as a code snippet in C, I'll try it out! Thanks a lot!

Comment: Remy, will it be the same in case of an SSD as well?

Comment: What if you open your text file delete everything, then load a text stream of blank.gif into it then save, then delete your text file.. or write and read from heap instead of using a file..

Comment: When overwriting an existing file, the operating system COULD make a copy of the original file and then do the overwrites on the copy, replacing the system's pointer to the file with a pointer to the new disk start. I know of at least one OS that did this when the original file was extremely fragmented.

Comment: How about mapping the locations in the disk where the file is and writing those areas with garbage values? That works in theory, but how would I map the locations where the file is present. Specially if its fragmented highly like you mentioned.

Comment: If OS is a problem you may need to overwrite/disable it first, forensically..lol

Comment: The solution to this problem is not programming, it's a **drive shredder**. You can't wipe disks like you used to. Even HDDs are starting to have SSD accelerator components on them, and those are hard to zero out properly. You can't recover a drive from tiny particles of plastic, metal and glass.

Comment: Its easy to zero out if the complete disk is under consideration like I mentioned. You can serially zero out a complete drive or a physical disk for that matter. But doing it to a file/directory is where it gets complex.

Comment: As @tadman says,  but OP mentions forensic techniques, which might be able to recover residual magnetic data at the edges of the track in the physical medium. My favourite method is with a hammer and chisel. But even then, I understand that the US was able to peice together remnants from a paper shredder last century.

Comment: @WeatherVane And eye protection! With an SSD drive, even a hybrid, you're going to have to smash up any little chips you find as well unless you know exactly what the flash chips look like. They can be pretty tiny and hide in non-obvious places. Same principle here applies to phones and other electronic devices with persistent storage.

Comment: Note that journalled file systems — where SSD is 'just' a variant on the theme — make it remarkably hard to overwrite old data.

Comment: CD/DVD is bad! Flakes everywhere. Smash it inside a bag (you are outside).

Comment: Good luck _testing_ that code :)

Comment: @TotalAnimeImmersion even with the full disk scenario, you cannot reliably erase the contents. Even if you serially write zeros, some sectors could have been replaced by backup sectors and the old ones could still have your data. So the solution is not through software.

Comment: Why don't you use some sort of encryption and store the key in a place which can be reliably erased, like a piece of paper. Although this reduces the problem to erasing the key, the key size is significantly smaller than the data and probably easy to realiably erase.

Comment: An AES encryption key of 128-bits with a key generated from random bits is not brute forcible in the life of the universe and a 256-bit key will withstand future quantum computers. The catch is the key, that is why when using a password it must not be on a 10 million frequently used passwords list and a key extension or derivation method that takes ~100ms is required such as bcrypt, PBKDF2 or Argon2 is required.

Comment: `FSCTL_GET_RETRIEVAL_POINTERS` can be used to retrieve this data. It's probably just as good to zero the file directly as first suggested by  @RemyLebeau - If file size doesn't change then location on disk won't change. But maybe the disk was defragmented earlier then there is no solution. SSD's have their own software to deal with this.

Answer (score 3):

Any kind of software technique cannot reliably zero out a file system, let alone a single file or directory. You need to abandon this approach.

Now your other option is to physically destroy to bits. Yes it works, but come on. You cannot destroy a disk every time you want to destroy a file.

The other more feasible option is to always encrypt your data while storing in the file. This reduces the problem to erasing only the key. But since it is significantly smaller, you can put it on a piece of paper. Now you just have to tear that paper and do a normal delete on the file. Even if "they" recover the encrypted contents, they can't do anything with it.

Although there are factors to consider. When reading the file, you have to be careful that the data remains "in memory" only. You might say, I will never write the unencrypted stuff to the disk. But the OS might do it. Say it swaps your process out.

So you need to carefully design your viewer. It should decrypt the file only into memory pages which are pinned. You might need to write some kernel modules for it. You also have to be careful about how you send the data to your display driver and what it does with it. Yes, it is doable with enough kernel modules. But each step from decryption to drawing pixels on the screen needs to be carefully audited.

Comment: Nice try, but at some point you have to type in that key. Then the system swaps out the memory to disk .. etc.

Comment: @WeatherVane pin the pages that hold the key :) write custom key board drivers!

Comment: Or a even simpler option, disable the secondary storage after the encrypted stuff has been read.

Comment: Do I have to do that every time I enter a password too?

Comment: @WeatherVane, the password is entered only after HD is unmounted. And is remounted only after a reboot. RAM is easy to clean. I agree at this point it is getting less and less usable. But the point of my answer is highlighting that a pure software solution is very difficult to implement. Your comments actually support that.

Answer (score 2):

[Meta answer]

Good news:

> **Turn on device encryption**
>
> Device encryption helps protect your data by encrypting it. Only someone with the right encryption key (such as a password) can decrypt it.

Bad news:

> Device encryption is not available in Windows 10 Home.

The Lord giveth and the Lord taketh away, see: https://support.microsoft.com/en-gb/help/4028713/windows-10-turn-on-device-encryption

Comment: You can still encrypt individual files in Home edition using APIs or external libraries. This relies on some level obfuscation but it's good enough in practice.